# Moving system file across drives results in fAnyOperationsAborted is TRUE, when using Shell32DLL SHFileOperation/SHFILEOPSTRUCT

Tags: c#, winapi, shell32.dll

When using the Shell32DLL SHFileOperation for file operations, I came across an issue related to moving system file(s) across drives (eg. c:\ to d:).

When moving, the user will be prompted by a system dialog asking "Are you sure you want to move this system file? [Yes, Skip, Cancel]"

Here is the core essence of my move operation:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT struc = new SHFILEOPSTRUCT();
struc.pFrom = fromPtr;
struc.pTo = toPtr;
struc.wFunc = FO_MOVE;
struc.fFlags = 0; // no relevant flags for this
struc.hwnd = 0;
struc.lpszProgressTitle = string.Empty;
struc.fAnyOperationsAborted = false; // initialized to FALSE

int res = SHFileOperation(ref struc);
```

The operation returns 0x0 i.e. success, but the returned fAnyOperationsAborted is TRUE, even though the user accepted to move the system file. I would expect the operation to return fAnyOperationsAborted=FALSE in that case.

The problem is that I am not able to distinguish between the user accepting, skipping or cancelling the operation, as fAnyOperationsAborted is TRUE in all three cases.

How to solve this issue?

MSDN on SHFileOperation function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why move shell32dll for file operations? why not use normal file operations?

Comment: @BugFinder The shell knows about connected files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `FOF_NOCONFIRMATION` and/or `FOF_NO_UI` flags help?

If not you can use [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx) instead (Vista+). If you add a sink then `IFileOperationProgressSink::PostMoveItem` will tell you the `HRESULT` of each move operation.

Comment: I do want the confirmations, as I want my file explorer to behave like normal Windows Explorer, meaning that FOF_NOCONFIRMATIONS, FOF_NO_UI are not relevant ie. should be kept false